# Make a copy of a file and remove the lines which fulfill the condition?

Tags: python, parsing

I want to parse a csv file with python. To do that, I want to create a copy of the same file, and then parse it line by line.

If one of the lines fulfills the condition, I want that line to be removed from the temporary file, and placed to a new file.

In this way I can make the tmp smaller and smaller as it iterates over the list, so there is less to parse, as well as see whether the temporary file is empty in the end of the parsing, and confirm that my parsing has worked fine. Whereas, I will not have damaged the original file.

---

Let's say the original file contains:

```
AAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCC
AAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBB
```

then I have a list

```
list = [AAAAAAAAA, BBBBBBBBBB,CCCCCCCCCC]
```

and I can do something in the lines of:

```
for x in list:
   for line in tmpCsv:
       if x in line:
            #remove line from tmpCsv place it to file x.CSV
```

Comment: What, specifically, are you having trouble with? (I'd probably try to read line by line from original file, and write to one of two other files if the conditional passes.)

Comment: I don't know how to create the temporary file without affecting the original one, and then use the temporary file for doing further parsing while modifying it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filesystems do not work that way. You cannot efficiently remove something from the middle of a file on disk. To simulate this action, the operating system first copy each byte in the file following the removed line to cover up the "hole", and finally the file to throw away the end bytes. Each line removal done this way has O(n) complexity, where `n` is file size, and removing all lines requires O(n<sup>2</sup>) - which is slow.

If the files are small enough, you can read the whole file and keep in in memory. If they're too big to keep in RAM (gigabytes), read portion-by-portion and process each one separately (if that's possible).

It's not required to remove the matched lines to do what you apparently want to do. You can just count the number of lines matched and print an error if the number is zero.

A more efficient implementation is possible, but this should work for start:

```
for x in list:
   numberOfLinesMatched = 0
   for line in tmpCsv:
       if x in line:
           numberOfLinesMatched += 1 # possibly break here
   if numberOfLinesMatched == 0:
       ... # print an error, not found in the file
```

Comment: but by deleting lines from the tmp file I thought that it gets smaller and smaller and there is less to parse as I iterate over the elements in the list. Obviously this does not hold true, right?

Comment: First of all, any operations on disk are orders of magnitudes slower than operations in RAM. Unless the files are huge there's no need to operate with disk files. Second, there are ways to improve this code for sure, but that's a bit beyond the scope of the question. Deleting elements from middle of the the list is slow for the same reason as for a file. Using a more efficient data structure is the way to go (a dictionary or `collections.Counter`).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the parsed data will be smaller than the entire file. So you are correct in putting the smaller set on the outer for loop. But you should be able to do this in just one pass. Below I give an example of a potential solution.

This reads the file line by line. If the line meets the condition described in paragraph 2, then it is placed in one file. If it fails to meet the condition, it is placed in a different file.

```
import os
if os.path.exists("match.csv") or os.path.exists("nonmatch.csv"):
    raise False, "I AM NOT OVERWRITING A FILE"
originalCsv = open(csvFile,'r')
matchFile = open("match.csv","w"
nonmatchFile = open("nonmatch.csv","w"
while 1:
    line = originalCsv.read()
    if line == '': break
    if line == meetsCondition:
        nonmatchFile.writelines(line)
    else:
        matchFile.writelines(line)
 matchFile.close()
 nonmatchFile.close()
 originalCsv.close()
```